# networking VM on proxmox 4.4

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, virtualbox, proxmox

I installed proxmox 4.4 on virtualbox and after installation I am not allowed to access to internet.

when i ping 8.8.8.8 I got a "network unreacheble"

My host and the vm are in the same IP rank. I can access to proxmox interface via my browser

Comment: Not a programming question - try [sf] ?

Comment: What is the configuration on Virtualbox? Can you send the output of ifconfig on Proxmox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you check your VMs networking config (in vbox). It sounds a lot like you have "host only" networking configured. "Bridged" is what you'll want.